# JBOSS 7.1.1 help changing ejb security-realm

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I'm trying to change ejb connection realm to use Jaas. But before that, I tried this **simple test** and stops to work (Below). Any Idea?

A create this realm:

```
 <security-realm name="SherlockRealm">
            <authentication>
                <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>

        </security-realm>
```

It's equals ApplicationRealm
and a replace

```
 <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
```

by

```
<connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="SherlockRealm"/>
```

When I do that, I cant call EJB by a Remote Client. It throws this error:

```
Remote connection failed: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed
Jun 25, 2014 10:27:59 AM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector setupEJBReceivers
WARN: Could not register a EJB receiver for connection to remote://localhost:4447
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.IoFutureHelper.get(IoFutureHelper.java:91)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.setupEJBReceivers(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:121)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.<init>(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:78)
    at br.ufmg.lcc.sherlock.view.login.LoginDialog$3.run(LoginDialog.java:140)
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I had the exact same error recently and it turned out to be a missing library.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't think it's  my case, because if I use the applicationReam it works.